# Como seleccionar muchos usuarios para una sola variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables

Tengo este codigo:

```
if (isset($_POST['invitar'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['gratuito']) {
        $usuario_receptor = $_SESSION['gratuito'];
    } else if ($_SESSION['exclusivo']) {
        $usuario_receptor = $_SESSION['exclusivo'];
    } else if ($_SESSION['admin']) {
        $usuario_receptor = $_SESSION['admin'];
    } else if ($_SESSION['creador']) {
        $usuario_receptor = $_SESSION['creador'];
    }
```

Esto es lo unico que se necesita para mi duda, supongo que es super sencilla, pero no tengo los conocimientos suficientes.
Como ven, tengo 4 `if`, para 4 sesiones (gratuito, exclusivo, admin y creador) y los 4 `if` toman la misma variable (`$usuario_receptor`). ¿Cómo hago para solo tener una línea de código que diga que tanto usuario gratuito, exclusivo, admin y creador son la misma variable? Intenté con un `$_SESSION = $usuario_receptor` pero no funcionó.
Gracias por la ayuda que puedan aportarme :D.

Comment: :o, pense que no funcionaba con los if, gracias.

Comment: No espera, con la variable que hago? ya que diria "$usuario_receptor = $_SESSION['gratuito']

Comment: Sirve "$usuario_receptor = $_SESSION['gratuito'] || $_SESSION['exclusivo'] ||  $_SESSION['admin'] ||  $_SESSION['creador']"???

Comment: Por qué no manejas roles de los usuarios? Solo buscarías en la tabla que rol pertenece al usuario y asignas a `$usuario_receptor`

Comment: Asi es como lo tengo, cada SESSION es un tipo de usuario, 0, 1, 2 y 3, quizas lo estoy haciendo mal, pero funciona, asi que estoy feliz xdxdx, ademas, aunque lo hiciera de la manera que dices ¿No tendria que hacer lo mismo? en plan "Si la session es tal, esta variable, si la sesion es tal, esta otra"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es el `select * from roles` de acuerdo al login del usuario y luego con ese valor crear la sesión dinámica.

Entonces suponiendo que ya tienes el valor del rol tendrías:

```
$sql = mysqli_query(aqui_tu_select);
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rol = "";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rol = $row["rol"]; //Suponiendo obtienes admin
  }
```

Creamos la sesión dinámica:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION[$rol] = $rol;
echo $_SESSION[$rol]; // Te imprime admin
$usuario_receptor = $_SESSION[$rol];//Aquí asignas el rol a la variable
```

Comment: No estoy seguro si entendi tu respuesta, pero si es como yo creo, ahi me estas diciendo como seleccionar el rol de un usuario, supongo que se me entendio mal, asi que voy a editar mi pregunta y hacerla mas clara.

Comment: La creación de la sesión dinámica, lo del rol solo le puse de ejemplo

Comment: Ahhh si, ya lo entiendo, mi error, te di un puntito pero soy muy nuevo y no tengo reputacion xdxd gracias, me re sirve

Comment: @SilviaManquis si es la respuesta márcala como la solución, así ayudas a otros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema.